# update quantity in shopping cart php (update array value)

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am not trying to be condescending, just being clear.

So! I have a session containing arrays. 
I have 'id' which is set using GET['id'] from URL (example: php?id=1). 
I also have 'qty' which is automatically 1.

When a few id numbers are added to the session, lets say    id =>1 , id => 2 ,  id => 3, and of course the qty => 1 for all three arrays.

I would like to update the 'qty' value of 'id' number 2, without changing the 'qty' value of the other id numbers (1 and 3). And I would like to do that for each individual id.

Bellow is my code, and to run it save it as cart.php. Then run it three times, the first time localhost/cart.php?=1 , localhost/cart.php?=2 , localhost/cart.php?=3. So that you have the three id numbers stored in your session. Then go to cart.php.

**index.php**
    **code

```
 <div class="product">
 <h3>Baketball</h3>
 <a href="add-to-cart.php?id=1">Add to cart</a>
 </div>

 <div class="product">
 <h3>Football</h3>
 <a href="add-to-cart.php?id=2">Add to cart</a>
 </div>

 <div class="product">
 <h3>Baseball</h3>
 <a href="add-to-cart.php?id=3">Add to cart</a>
 </div>
```

**cart.php**
    **code

```
// set the array and store in session

$_SESSION['items'][]=array(     
                        'id'=>"'".$_GET['id']."'",
                        'qty'=> 1                            
                    ); 

// Display each array value stored in the session

foreach ($_SESSION['items'] as $value) {

// Display the id
echo 'The ID is ' ."''''" . $value['id'] ."''''" ;
// Display the Qty
echo 'the QTY  ' ."''''" . $value['qty'] ."''''" ;

echo "<br/>";

//Display and edit quantity in a form.
echo "<form method='post' action='id.php' name='edit'>

<p>Quantity:  <input type=\"text\" size=\"20\" name='".$value['id']."' value='".$value['qty']."'/> </p><br>            

<input class='save' name='update' value='update' type='submit'>

</form>";

}

// check if the update button is submited so that the qty value can be changed where the id number of the selected qty input box is edited
if (isset($_POST["update"])) {
 $_SESSION['item'][$id]= $_POST["'".$value['id']."'"];
}

?>
```

Comment: it doesnt work. Thanks anywas for the help

Answer (score 0):

I'm not seeing where `$id` is set in the rest of the code you've posted. So I'll define it again here, just to be sure.

Change your inputs to this:

```
echo "<p>ID: <input type='text' name='id' value='" . $value['id'] . "'></p>";
echo "<p>Quantity:  <input type='text' size='20' name='qty' value='" . $value['qty'] . "'/></p>";
```

The id field should ideally be type="hidden", but at least you can see the number for testing.

Then you can use this to update your session:

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$qty = $_POST['qty'];
$_SESSION['item'][$id] = $qty;
```

Comment: rjdown- thanks for you response. I have a add product to cart page which looks like this <a href="add-to-cart.php?id=1">Add to cart</a>. Each product will have a different id. and I would like to change the quantities after adding them to cart

Comment: $_SESSION['item'][$id]++; always increase it by 1. i need an input box that increases the value

Comment: I see, then you are going to need more than one input. I will update my answer soon.

Comment: Wait hold on...! If you're updating via a URL, what is the form for?

Comment: thank you so much for your help. its a shopping cart

Comment: it will have an index page containing this code <div class="product">
 <h3>Baseball</h3>
 <a href="add-to-cart.php?id=5555">Add to cart</a>
</div>

Comment: ill upload the index page

Comment: ok try that, now you have two inputs, one for ID and one for quantity

Comment: I've added the index page to set the id numbers. And i will try the code now thanks :)

Comment: the two input boxes are there, but when I insert a number and update it, it doesnt update. it just creates a new array to the session. Just like as thought I am refreshing the page

Comment: Hmm... do you have `session_start();` at the top of the page?